# sort a file based on the field 3 of the file contents

Tags: scripts, sort

This is the contents of file

```
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000    #Q  2
```

I want to sort on field 3($3)

```
08/03/2015 09:35:15.934
```

Can someone help

Comment: What's the format of the date? Day, month, year?

Answer (score 2):

### Using `sort` and `awk`

Suppose your date format is the following

`08/03/2015` –> Day, month, year

using the command below.

- It's **one** command (note the `\` at the end of the lines)
- Replace `your_input_file` with your file name.

*The command*

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==3) {printf "%s/%s/%s\t",substr($3,7,4),substr($3,4,2),substr($3,1,2)} else {printf "%s\t",$i}} printf "\n"}' your_input_file |\
sort -k3 -k4 |\
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==3) {printf "%s/%s/%s\t",substr($3,9,2),substr($3,6,2),substr($3,1,4)} else {printf "%s\t",$i}} printf "\n"}'
```

*Breakdown*

- The first `awk` command corrects the date from `day/month/year`

  ```
  08/03/2015
  ```

  to `year/month/day`

  ```
  2015/03/08
  ```
- The `sort` command sorts the new structure
- The second `awk` makes changes to the first `awk` undo

---

If your date format isn't `day/month/year`, you have to change the part

- `substr($3,7,4),substr($3,4,2),substr($3,1,2)`

  and
- `substr($3,9,2),substr($3,6,2),substr($3,1,4)`

*Explanation*

`substr(field,start_position,length)`

- `field`

  do not change, it's the third column
- `start_position`, `length`

  return a substring from `start_position` with a length of `length`

---

*Example*

The input file `foo`

`cat foo`

```
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2016 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       03/07/2016 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2016 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
```

The output of

`awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==3) {printf "%s/%s/%s\t",substr($3,7,4),substr($3,4,2),substr($3,1,2)} else {printf "%s\t",$i}} printf "\n"}' foo | sort -k3 -k4 | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (i==3) {printf "%s/%s/%s\t",substr($3,9,2),substr($3,6,2),substr($3,1,4)} else {printf "%s\t",$i}} printf "\n"}'`

```
090100010000481074  1   07/03/2015  09:35:15.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q  2   
090100010000481074  1   07/03/2015  09:35:17.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q  2   
090100010000481074  1   08/03/2015  09:35:15.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q  2   
090100010000481074  1   08/03/2015  09:35:15.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q  2   
090100010000481074  1   08/03/2015  09:35:17.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q  2   
090100010000481074  1   07/03/2016  09:35:17.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q  2   
090100010000481074  1   08/03/2016  09:35:17.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q  2   
090100010000481074  1   03/07/2016  09:35:15.934    LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy ELF 100 1980000 119 3   2   1890000 119 100 2040000 119 100 1980000 119 1000    #Q
```

Comment: You are forgetting the fact that you need to revert the date format first. The date sorting is incorrect this way.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Oh, you mean 2015/03/08?

Comment: Exactly :) Otherwise it will sort on day/month/year instead of year/month/day.

Comment: @JacobVlijm done :)

Comment: works very nicely!

Comment: @canonical  If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** on the left hand site of my answer now turning it into beautiful green. If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow... If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `08/03/2015` means`8th March, 2015`, you can use this `bash` one liner :

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do parts=( $(echo "$line") ); printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --date="$(sed -r 's_([^/]+/)([^/]+/)_\2\1_' <<<"${parts[2]} ${parts[3]}")" '+%s')" "$line"; done <file.txt | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Expanded form :

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    parts=( $(echo "$line") ) 
    printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --date="$(sed -r 's_([^/]+/)([^/]+/)_\2\1_' <<<"${parts[2]} ${parts[3]}")" '+%s')" "$line" 
done <file.txt | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

- We are reading each line of the input file and putting it as variable `line`
- `parts` array will contain the different parts if teh `line` separated on whitespaces
- Then we are getting the epoch time of the relevant date-time fields after extracting them and setting in correct format using `sed`
- From the loop we will output the epoch time first and then the original `line` after that
- Now as we have the epoch at first we can use `sort` numerically to get out data sorted according to the first field
- Finally we have removed the epoch time to get our final output.

**Example (Taken from @A.B.) :**

```bsh
$ cat file.txt 
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2016 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       03/07/2016 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2016 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2


$ while IFS= read -r line; do parts=( $(echo "$line") ); printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --date="$(sed -r 's_([^/]+/)([^/]+/)_\2\1_' <<<"${parts[2]} ${parts[3]}")" '+%s')" "$line"; done <file.txt | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2015 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2016 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2016 09:35:17.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
090100010000481074      1       03/07/2016 09:35:15.934 LA150803000AJSX00000    LA150803000AJSX CRBP    Buy     ELF     100     1980000 119     3       2       1890000 119     100     2040000 119     100     1980000 119     1000   #Q  2
```

On the other hand, if `08/03/2015` means `3rd August, 2015` you can use (no need for `sed` to get the right format that `date` would understand) :

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do parts=( $(echo "$line") ); printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --date="${parts[2]} ${parts[3]}" '+%s')" "$line"; done <file.txt | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Expanded form :

```bsh
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    parts=( $(echo "$line") ) 
    printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --date="${parts[2]} ${parts[3]}" '+%s')" "$line" done <file.txt | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Comment: the `sed` part is very nice =)

Comment: @A.B. I primarily thought the input format is `mm/dd/yy`, then saw your example and found that the format is `dd/mm/yy` so have to include `sed` to make the input properly formatted for `date` :)

Comment: Ok thanks but is there way i can check that the file is sorted properly on field 3 so that i need not do this?

Comment: @canonical GNU `date` does not understand the format `dd/mm/yy` (e.g. `27/12/2015`), it treat it as `mm/dd/yy`..so as you have `08/03/2015` which is in `dd/mm/yy` format we need to convert it to `mm/dd/yy` (`03/08/2015`) first using `sed`..so if you have the date in `mm/dd/yy` then no conversion is needed hence would be much simpler..

Comment: @heemayl No the format is mm/dd/yy...it is aug 3rd.it need not be converted....Is there script to check if the file is already sorted properly before i try sorting my self?

Comment: @canonical Well then, its much easier now : `while IFS= read -r line; do parts=( $(echo "$line") ); printf '%s %s\n' "$(date --date="${parts[2]} ${parts[3]}" '+%s')" "$line"; done <file.txt | sort -k1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-` ..also note that any check to ensure whether they are sorted would require the same procedure of reading the file and then checking..so this one liner would tackle both, if they are sorted then ok, if not they will be sorted..

Comment: @canonical check my edits..

Comment: @heemayl I want to print the lione that is offset of the time...dont sort it back...I want to print lines that were not sorted

Answer (score 0):

Nice question.

#### The main issue in your question

The main issue in your question is that you actually want to sort by *two* fields (date, time), of which one needs to be reverted (read backwards) before sorting, since the date is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

If we do that (in a verbose way for clarity reasons), the script below does that. It:

- first reverts the date, combines it with the time field, creates a tuple i.c.w. the line index.
- sorts the list of tuples by date/time and prints out the original lines by the newly ordered indexes of the sorted list.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
rawlist = []

for i, l in enumerate(f):
    # split the line, read the date backwards for correct sorting, since it is dd/mm/yyyy now
    # add the time
    l = l.split(); cr = (i, l[2].split("/")[::-1]+l[3].split(":"))
    rawlist.append(cr)
# sort by date, time
rawlist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
# print the lines by found (sorted) indexes
for i in [d[0] for d in rawlist]:
    print(f[i], end = "")
```

#### How to use

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `sort_byfield.py`
- Run it with the file as an argument:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/sort_byfield.py <file>
  ```

#### Example

The list (left out a number of fields for clarity):

```
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2014 09:35:17.932 
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 08:22:15.934 
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:55:15.933 
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2013 09:01:15.934
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2013 08:35:15.934
```

then outputs:

```
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2013 08:35:15.934
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2013 09:01:15.934
090100010000481074      1       08/03/2014 09:35:17.932 
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 08:22:15.934 
090100010000481074      1       07/03/2015 09:55:15.933
```

#### Shorter version

If we do not care about readability so much, the version below is a shorter version of the same script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1]).readlines()
rawlist = [(i, l.split()[2].split("/")[::-1]+l.split()[3].split(":")) for i, l in enumerate(f)]
rawlist.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
[print(f[i], end = "") for i in [d[0] for d in rawlist]]
```